# Proper way to write a MySQL query that uses a derived column and multiple joins

Tags: mysql

This query is NOT legal syntax and I'm trying to understand what the efficient way of writing it is. This is what I have:

```
  SELECT a.*, b.id, lapsed FROM
    ( SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(day)) AS lapsed FROM c ) AS x 
  FROM first_table a
  INNER JOIN second_table b ON a.id = b.some_id
  INNER JOIN third_table c ON c.user_id = a.user_id
  WHERE a.some_col = 'm'
  AND b.num >= lapsed
```

There's three tables being joined. Normally this would be trivial, but the problem is my last part of the `WHERE` clause, specifically `b.num >= lapsed` is doing a comparison on a `derived` value. Is there a correct way to write this?

Comment: 2 FROM is not allowed. But a LEFT JOIN on a sub query is possible. And since it's one row in x, the join ON criteria can be (1=1).

Comment: any chance you can submit a query as the answer so I can mark it accordingly?

Comment: You and I have differing ideas about where the problem lies in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the MAX() aggregate, it looks like you want the latest `day` value for each `user_id` value from `third_table`.

To get that, we can write a query like this:

```
  SELECT c.user_id
       , DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),MAX(c.day)) AS lapsed
    FROM third_table c
   GROUP BY c.user_id
```

You can use the resultset from this query as a rowsource in another query, by using that query as a inline view in place of a table reference. (MySQL refers to an inline view as a "derived table".)

We just wrap that query in parens, and use it in place of where we would normally find a table reference.  The inline view (derived table) will need to be assigned an alias.

For example:

```
 SELECT a.*
      , b.id
      , d.lapsed
   FROM first_table a
   JOIN second_table b
     ON b.some_id = a.id
   JOIN ( SELECT c.user_id
               , DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),MAX(c.day)) AS lapsed
            FROM third_table c
           GROUP BY c.user_id
        ) d
     ON d.user_id = a.user_id   
  WHERE a.some_col = 'm'
    AND b.num > d.lapsed
```

A query similar to that should run. But whether that returns the resultset you expect to achieve, that really depends on what result you are attempting to return. Absent a specification (apart from some invalid query syntax), we're just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, but if the subquery is correct then this should work.

I also assumed that the 'c' in the example of the question is also referring to that third_table and not some table/view called c.

And the INNER JOIN to third_table was commented out, since it's mostly useless to INNER JOIN table/views when you don't use any fields of it. Well, it could be used to limit on records that are in that table, but most often it's just useless to do that.

```sql
SELECT a.*, b.id, x.lapsed 
FROM first_table a
INNER JOIN second_table b ON a.id = b.some_id
--INNER JOIN third_table c ON c.user_id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(day)) AS lapsed 
    FROM third_table
) AS x ON (1=1)
WHERE a.some_col = 'm'
AND b.num >= x.lapsed;
```